# tensorflow giving an error regarding data shape

Tags: tensorflow

i have a tensorflow model which when i input data into gives an error
this is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import openpyxl as xl
import numpy as np
while True:   
    wb = xl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:\\tbp.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active
    test = np.array([377, 24459, 7023844000, 305, 319, 281, -24, -7.87])
    print(test.shape)
    datatobepredicted = [None] * 8
    predicteddata = [[None]*5]*1585
    sigmoid = tf.keras.models.load_model("C:\\Users\\SMTL\\Desktop\\python projects\\AI\\models\\sigmoid")
    print(sigmoid.predict(np.array(test)))
```

and this is the error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 13, but 
received input with shape (None, 1)
```

i tried using .reshape(-1,1) but it gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where the error is, but what the error says is the contrary of what you've done : the size of the last dimension (-1) must be 13 and not 1, not of the 1st dimension. Normally the first dimension is used as the batch size. Maybe just try to do :

```
model.predict(np.array([test]))
```

Even though, the test shape does not correspond to what the model expects(if I assume the "dense" layer is the first layer : `8!= 13`). One of them has be changed

Answer (score 0):

You could try entering a singleton dimension (a dimension of length one) for your batch. Also it's expecting 13 inputs. I'm familiar with Pytorch, not Tensorflow, but in Pytorch, Sequential is designed to take batches by default. This is what I would try in Pytorch:

```
test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
test = torch.from_numpy(test).unsqueeze(0)
```

I believe the equivalent for that line is this:

```
test = tf.expand_dims(test, axis=0)
```

You list should probably be standing upright, anywho, and you should have 13 elements in each of your batches.

Comment: i applied your suggestion and now it gives a new error 
Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 13, but 
received input with shape (None, 1)

Comment: @tahookahoo Your input is still the wrong size. When you print out your input, what does it look like? It may benefit you to put the test = test.reshape(-1,13) instead of test = tf.expand_dims(test, axis=0), if that doesn't work try test = test.reshape(13, -1).

Comment: the shape is TensorShape([1, 8])
and the value is tf.Tensor(
[[ 3.770000e+02  2.445900e+04  7.023844e+09  3.050000e+02  3.190000e+02
   2.810000e+02 -2.400000e+01 -7.870000e+00]], shape=(1, 8), 
dtype=float32)

Comment: At this point you should just need a greater number of inputs. You only have eight. If you add five more inputs to it, the shape should be correct. Please try test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]) instead of test = np.array([377, 24459, 7023844000, 305, 319, 281, -24, -7.87]) and it should work.

Comment: nope doesn't work now it says:     ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 13, but 
received input with shape (None, 1)

Comment: That's weird... it seems to indicate that the input is changing shape. You're printing the input right before you put it into the model?